# how to delete a exposed port from a docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I need to delete a port from the image and for some reason I can't recreate the image frome base image. How can I remove a port that exposes?

I took this image where a port was exposed

docker ps:

```
beddbd08c417   new:new   "/bin/sh"   4 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   9010/tcp   dazzling_pike
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gitlabregistry.isaco.ir/elyas/oicnode16
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh" ]
```

Comment: what do you mean you can't recreate the image? do you get an error? also why do you want to "remove a port"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for removing an exposed port:

1. Ignore it. It's documentation and doesn't affect container networking unless you run a specific command that uses this metadata.
2. Create a new base image without this exposed port. If they are exposing ports that you don't want exposed in your image, then there may be functionality in the base image you don't want. If you are changing configuration from the base image, evaluate if that makes more sense to happen in the base image.
3. Mutate the image after it's been created. I'm not a huge fan of that for this scenario, but if neither of the above options works, you can save the image from docker and change the json configuration. In my own project, regctl has an image mod command that does this for images in a registry (or you can import an image from docker save to an ocidir):

```
$ regctl image copy nginx:latest localhost:5000/library/nginx:latest

$ regctl image config localhost:5000/library/nginx:latest --format '{{jsonPretty .Config.ExposedPorts}}'
{
  "80/tcp": {}
}

$ regctl image mod --expose-rm "80/tcp" localhost:5000/library/nginx:latest --create no-expose
localhost:5000/library/nginx:no-expose

$ regctl image config localhost:5000/library/nginx:no-expose --format '{{jsonPretty .Config.ExposedPorts}}'
null
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to cancel an [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) directive once it's been set, whether in the base image or earlier in the same image.  Further `EXPOSE` lines will just expose more ports.  (`VOLUME` and `LABEL` also add values to lists and work the same way.)

On the other hand, in modern Docker, "exposing a port" means almost nothing.  Ports that are exposed but not published show up in `docker ps` output, and the unusual `docker run -P` option (capital `P`) publishes all exposed ports on arbitrary host ports, but that's about it.

So practically, I'd just ignore this; let your derived container include the base image's port in `docker ps` even if nothing is actually running there.

Comment: But it's annoying and does not look clean! I'm amazed that they did not include a command to remove things easily from the metadata. That is just crazy. If I use another image that has 4 ports exposed that has absolutely no use to me, it's pretty annoying to have that mixed in with the exposed ports that DO matter to me.